# I am getting a 403 error after I login to the Control Panel

Tags: admin

I have a problem after installing Craft on a live server (local with MAMP everything works fine). I could install it with composer but when I login to /admin then I will redirect to a 403 page... and everything is a 403 error till I clear cookies :/

*Update*:

I think my problem is that Craft somehow generates two Cookies after logging in. when I delete one, the 403 disappears and I can enter the admin dashboard, but when I logout and login again - two cookies again and the 403 error ... :frowning:

Comment: Is it a Craft styled 403 page or a web server styled one? Can you share a pic of the cookies you're referring to?

Comment: So what does the php and/or apache log says? In these log files you should have the exact error message.

Comment: Hey guys, I am in contact now with the hosting provider. I think its hosting dependent because on a other server it is working as expected. thanks!